# Yeoman composeWith cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yeoman, npm-install

really stumped with this one.
I've written a generator, which has other generators inside it.

When I have it installed from my local copy using npm link composewith works fine, but when I install the generator from github, I get the error cannot find module.

My compose with function looks like this:

```
this.composeWith("rawnet:static", {
  options: {
    appname: this.appname,
    git: this.git,
    gruntPath: this.sourceRoot()
  }
}, {
  local: require.resolve('../static')
});
```

And my folder structure looks like this:

```
-app  
  -index.js  
-static  
  -index.js
```

The error I am getting is:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '../static'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
    at module.exports.generators.Base.extend.generateSite (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-rawnet/app/index.js:79:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-rawnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:421:16
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:543:15)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:523:5)
```

Has anyone else come up against this, I don't understand why when I run the generator from my local it works fine, but as soon as I install it from github using npm it fails. I've checked all the paths and they are correct, I've even changed it to point to exactly the right folder after npm has installed the generator and it still doesn't work.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after pulling my hair out all night, a fresh look this morning through the yeoman docs on creating a generator and I figured out what the issue was.

I hadn't included my sub generators in the `files` array of `package.json`.